# Count Mondays in a given date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How can I count the Mondays in a given date range using javascript or jquery? The date range would be like this:

```
(2016-02-22 to 2016-02-29)
```

I searched a lot but in the last I got nothing. Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Why tag this with PHP if you want it done in JS? 2) this can be done in a straightforward loop 3) What have you tried? At the moment this is a 'write my code for me' request, not a question.

Answer (score 3):

try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/e43rs5n4/1/)

```
function getCountOf( date1, date2, dayToSearch )
{

    var dateObj1 = parseDate(date1);
    var dateObj2 = parseDate(date2);

    var count = 0;

    var week = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

    var dayIndex = week.indexOf( dayToSearch );

    while ( dateObj1.getTime() <= dateObj2.getTime() )
    {
       if (dateObj1.getDay() == dayIndex )
       {
          count++
       }

       dateObj1.setDate(dateObj1.getDate() + 1);
    }

    return count;
}
```